# How do I list google google business profile locations from an account ID using google business profile API without getting a 429?

Tags: google-api, google-business-profile-api

I have been approved for the google business profile api after folliwing the prerequisites and gaining approval for access found [here](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/prereqs). Continuing, per the instructions in the project in the google business cloud dashboard I have added the following API's:
Google My Business API PRIVATE
My Business Account Management API
My Business Business Calls API
My Business Business Information API
My Business Lodging API
My Business Notifications API
My Business Place Actions API
My Business Q&A API
My Business Verifications API

Continuing per the instructions found [here](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/basic-setup) for basic set up, I am able to get to the point when I can get the Account ID of the person authorized in the Google api playground.

With the exception of search functionality, when trying to do anything related to the scope of businessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com all my requests return a 429. For example, the following request:
https://mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/1023160XXXXX/locations

```
{
  "error": {
    "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED", 
    "message": "Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Requests' and limit 'Requests per minute' of service 'mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:40740XXXXXX'.", 
    "code": 429, 
    "details": [
      {
        "reason": "RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED", 
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo", 
        "domain": "googleapis.com", 
        "metadata": {
          "service": "mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com", 
          "quota_limit": "DefaultRequestsPerMinutePerProject", 
          "quota_location": "global", 
          "quota_metric": "mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/default_requests", 
          "quota_limit_value": "0", 
          "consumer": "projects/40740XXXXXXX"
        }
      }, 
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help", 
        "links": [
          {
            "url": "https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#requesting_higher_quota", 
            "description": "Request a higher quota limit."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Reviewing all the visible quotas related to the API I can't find any that say 0. I have filled out a general form for quoata increase as I can see nowhere in the dashboard where I can directly see the DefaultRequestsPerMinutePerProject setting to request a quota increase.

Since originally writing this a few days ago, I made a quota request increase via the google form, but I am not sure if that will address anything as it seems strange this would not be working "out of the box" after receiving approval prior for this api.

Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 0):

After contacting google api support, the 429 went away, there is nothing else that was done to resolve this issue.

I am unsure if it was related to my account specifically or if it was related to the normal expected process for using this endpoint on all accounts.